# Building JSON-Object with inner array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need this string:

> {"name":"ne","type":"Choice","id":"ne","width":150,"items":[{"id":"test1","value":"test1","title":"test1"},{"id":"test3","value":"test3","title":"test3"},{"id":"test2","value":"test2","title":"test2"}]}

I have the following:

`JSON.stringify(itemList)` gives me this:

> [{"id":"test1","value":"test1","title":"test1"},{"id":"test3","value":"test3","title":"test3"},{"id":"test2","value":"test2","title":"test2"}]

I tried this:

```
JSON.stringify({
      name: loadName(),
      type: "Choice",
      id: complexTableId,
      width: loadWidth(),
      items: JSON.stringify(itemList)
})
```

But I get this:

> {"name":"ne","type":"Choice","id":"ne","width":"150","items":"[{\"id\":\"test1\",\"value\":\"test1\",\"title\":\"test1\"},{\"id\":\"test3\",\"value\":\"test3\",\"title\":\"test3\"},{\"id\":\"test2\",\"value\":\"test2\",\"title\":\"test2\"}]"}

Does anyone know, where my mistake lies?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify({
                    name: loadName(),
                    type: "Choice",
                    id: complexTableId,
                    width: loadWidth(),
                    items: itemList
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

no need to call `JSON.stringify` on your items before stringifying everything, try this :

```
JSON.stringify({
    name: loadName(),
    type: "Choice",
    id: complexTableId,
    width: loadWidth(),
    items: itemList
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `JSON.stringify` on `itemList` twice. This will cause your *stringified object* to be stringified again.

Notice the two backslash + double quote (`\"`) in the double stringify example below:

```
// single stringify
> JSON.stringify({ test: "Hello World" });
< "{"test":"Hello World"}"

// double stringify
> JSON.stringify({ test: JSON.stringify("Hello World") });
< "{"test":"\"Hello World\""}"
```

If you want to properly stringify an object then only use `JSON.stringify` once on the whole object:

```
JSON.stringify({
    name: loadName(),
    type: "Choice",
    id: complexTableId,
    width: loadWidth(),
    items: itemList // don't include "JSON.stringify" here
});
```